# Eclipse wont start after computer restart

Tags: java, eclipse, editor

My eclipse is not starting because my computer kinda froze and so I had to force restart it. Eclipse was open when I had to restart and I believe that this is most likely the cause. I do not know how to fix this. Whenever I try opening it, it tells me to check the .log file inside my workspace and it says:

http://paste.strictfp.com/26579

And I don't know how to fix it. Please help?

Comment: Your workspace is probaby screwed. Have you tried on a clean empty workspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing classes *Line 125* Chances are you will have to reinstall to fix this.

Comment: Well that's the thing, I can't even switch my workspace because it won't even start up at all. And thanks for such quick responses! Very impressed with this site so far. The majority of the comments are telling me to restart eclipse, so I guess I will just give that a try and sync the workspace again.
And btw, can I get all of your opinions on a game that I made?:
The link is here: http://www.mediafire.com/?9137e3hb17cixh0
I made this game in Java in about 4 days. Tell me what you think. Thanks :P

Comment: And thanks a lot, it did work. :P I reinstalled it and now it works fine, I'm just hoping I can transfer my workspace properly. :P

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, If you find his question solved your issue make sure to accept it.

Comment: You can always manually rename your workspace on disk before starting Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I started windows Task Manager and force ended the javaw.exe / eclipse.exe processes and then tried starting up eclipse again. Worked for me.