# eclipse helios won't start

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eclipse wont start after computer restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609491/eclipse-wont-start-after-computer-restart)

Lately I opened my eclipse and other program but suddenly my Computer got hang so I turned it off without closing the programs and my eclipse. Then, when i started my computer and started eclipse, my eclipse won't start. it will only proceed to the loading page then i only got this window ...
[image]

I am using ubuntu for my OS.

is there anyway that i cannot re install again my eclipse?

do anyone have an idea about my case?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running eclipse with eclipse -clean command line option.

quoting documentation: 
if set to "true", any cached data used by the OSGi framework and eclipse runtime will be wiped clean. This will clean the caches used to store bundle dependency resolution and eclipse extension registry data. Using this option will force eclipse to reinitialize these caches.

this have helped me a few times before.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem many times and each time I ended up restoring my workspace from backup and importing projects. When I decided I've had enough, I performed a binary search and found the culprit. The solution is to delete the file `workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap`.